# Control + L not clearing screen

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

When I try to clear my terminal screen on OSX:

```
computer@ ~ () $ ^L
```

And when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> after that it just shows:

```
-bash:
   : command not found
```

Any ideas on how this happens?

My `.bash_profile`, `.profile`, and `.bashrc` are empty.

Comment: try to remap : `bind -x '"\C-l": clear'`

Comment: That worked, however I'm curious of how it came unbound.

Comment: i am not sure.. should check default value I don't know where they defined..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

remap control :

`bind -x '"\C-l": clear'`

Comment: This works in the session, but the problem always comes back in the next session. How can I make this persistent? EDIT: Phillppe's answer below worked. :)

Comment: sh: 4: bind: not found

Answer (score 8):

I typically have a `~/.inputrc` where I put following bindings

```
"\C-p":previous-history
"\C-n":next-history
"\C-a.":beginning-of-line
"\C-e.":end-of-line
"\C-l":clear-screen
```

Comment: +1 for the `.inputrc` solution.

Comment: Best answer here - it is persistent.